# What to return in a Firebase Cloud Function that has two or more methods that return a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function that listens to a change in `Firebase Database` and responds with a function that returns a `promise`.

```
exports.clean_up_anonymous_users =
  functions.database.ref('path/to/ref')
  .onWrite(event => {

    // Make Sure it's not a delete event
    if (!event.data.val()) {
      return 0;
    }

    const cleanUp = event.data.val();

    // Normal Boolean check of my value
    if (cleanUp === true) {

      // Deletes Anonymous Users (returns a promise)
      listAllUsers();

      // Removes the value from the Database (returns a promise)
      return removeFromQueue("path/to/ref");

    }

    // If cleanUp === false
    return 0;
  });

// ===============================================
// I think that's enough but if you wish, read on!
// ===============================================

function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        var userInfo = userRecord.providerData;
        if (userInfo.length === 0) {
          var uid = userRecord.uid;
          admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Successfully deleted user:", uid);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
            });
        }
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
}

function removeFromQueue(path) {
  admin.database().ref(path).remove()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
  });
}
```

This code works as expected but shows an error in the Log window:

> Error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

How to get rid of that Error?

Comment: Try adding return before firt line in body of listAllUsers function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two function defined in the end do indeed return `undefined` as they are not `return`ing anything. This would work in Ruby where last interpreted line in function body is `return`ed.

So add `return` before the start of bodies inside those functions as inside them you are working with Promise chain that would return Promise as their execution will finish.

So in your code there will be this:

```
return admin.auth()...
```

And

```
return admin.database()...
```

Comment: 1+ Thanks, that was it